# Description and file version from exe file

Tags: c++, qt, exe

How can i find in Qt, description, file version, date created or other related information from a executable file from windows.

Comment: As it is windows specific feature (executable meta data) you will have to find proper windows api for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By first taking a look at what google says about it :-) [Here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Get_the_file_information_in_Qt) the result

Comment: This doesn't answer to the question, QFileInfo does not provide file version.